# How to get code coverage on code for which the tests are in another module?

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a maven module containing code but no tests. Tests are in another module.

- code-module
- test-module

I use JaCoCo to report about the code coverage, but it seems that no JaCoCo report is generated in the code-module because there are no tests to run. Without such report, the aggregate report in the test-module does not include the code coverage from the code-module's code.

**How do I make sure the jacoco report is generated even when there are no tests?**

### Where I think the problem lies

I found out that the problem may lie with the way the `maven-surefire-plugin` handles the case where no tests are found.
The maven logs then show:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ code-module ---
```

followed by

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report (report) @ data-product-model ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
```

Adding a single test class (that may be empty) changes this output to

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ code-module ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.code.CodeCoverageTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in com.example.code.CodeCoverageTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

and suddenly it generates `surefire-reports/` and the `jacoco.exec` and `site/jacoco/`
(even though there are no actual tests, just an empty `CodeCoverageTest.java`),
so I see that the `jacoco-maven-plugin` is able to report:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report (report) @ code-module ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /workspaces/example/code-module/target/jacoco.exec
```

### Question

Instead of adding such a dummy test class, **is there a way to configure `maven-surefire-plugin` to generate the jacoco stuff always?**
Maybe something I can put in the parent pom, so it will automatically work for all child-module without tests.